# FUSE ESB broker

Tags: fuseesb, jbossfuse

Iam new to middle ware and fuse esb.I don't know how to start with it.

As i can see fuse is a combination of many open souce components like apache camel,Apache active mq,karaf etc.It will be time consuming to study each and every component seperately and iam short of time.

Any short cuts available,How to master fuse esb?

Regards,

Ravi

Answer (score 2):

JBoss Fuse can be a little daunting in the beginning, especially when you read about the gazillion different technologies and components, but in the end it's simpler than you think :)

If you're looking for a "quick start" from the all the documentation, I would skim through these four pages:

- [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) - what is the flow of information going to look like in your system?
- [Java DSL](http://camel.apache.org/java-dsl.html) - allows you to define `routes` so that the different components in your system can talk to each other.
- [Simple Expression Language](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) - like the name says, it's just a simple expression language, which you'll end up using a lot.
- [Maven Bundle Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) - Fuse makes heavy use of OSGi, and so you need to know how to build `bundles`, which are the building blocks for fuse `features`.

And then after reading those you should be able to understand how the examples work:

- [Fuse By Example](http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/fusebyexample.html) - an excellent selection of sample projects

Going through these examples should be the quickest way to get you up and running quickly - start with the [Hello Camel](https://github.com/FuseByExample/HelloCamel/blob/master/README.md) example (obviously!), and then try some of the others which are related to what you want to do (there are plenty of good examples there using persistence, transactions, ActiveMQ, fabric, etc).

I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Hi Steve,Thanks for your sugession.Will Follow the same                                                                                                                                    Regards,                                                            Ravi